# Determine if a number is the sum of two triangular numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is it possible to figure out if a number $z$ is the addition of two triangular number without recursion or finding the values to $x$ and $y$?

$$\frac{x(x+1)}{2} + \frac{y(y+1)}{2} = z$$

An example of this would be following:

$$\frac{345(345+1)}{2} + \frac{234(234+1)}{2} = 87180$$

Is it possible to determine if $87180$ originated from the addition of two triangular numbers without recursively going back and plugging every possibility for $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The equation:
$$ x(x+1)+y(y+1)=2z \tag{1}$$
is equivalent to:
$$ (2x+1)^2 + (2y+1)^2 = 8z+2 \tag{2} $$
hence $z$ is the sum of two triangular numbers **iff** $8z+2$ is the sum of two squares, i.e. iff for every prime $p$ of the form $4k+3$ that divides $8z+2$, $\nu_p(8z+2)$ is even.

In the given example, $z=87180$, we have:

$$ 8z+2 = 2\cdot 17 \cdot 73\cdot 281 \tag{3}$$
and every odd prime occurring in the RHS of $(3)$ is of the form $4k+1$, hence $8z+2$ can be written as the sum of two odd squares:
$$ 8z+2 = 101^2 + 829^2 \tag{4}$$
and $z$ is the sum of two triangular numbers:
$$ 87180 = \binom{51}{2}+\binom{415}{2}.\tag{5} $$

Comment: @FelipeFaria: I have just expanded my answer dealing with your example. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Perhaps the more interesting question is whether this can be done *without* factoring $8z+2$.

Comment: Indeed it is! Thank you.

Comment: what is $\nu_p$?

Comment: @MichaelChirico: the $p$-adic height, i.e. $$\nu_p(n)=\max\left\{m\in\mathbb{N}: p^m\mid n\right\}.$$

Comment: We can improve this to 4n+1, if we allow 0.

Comment: It is also equivalent to $(x+y+1)^2+(x-y)^2=4z+1$, thus avoiding a needless factor of 2. In this example, $4z+1=348721=465^2+364^2$.

Answer (score 3):

If we had $a(k)$ from [A008441](https://oeis.org/A008441) the test for $z$ would be
$$
a(z) > 0 .
$$

The information section on this series provides many interesting relations.