# Are there any two triangular numbers that add up to a perfect cube?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The triangular numbers are all of these numbers:

$$\sum_{n=1}^x n$$ For $x\gt 0$ and that $x$ are only integers.

Here's a list: $$1,3,6,10,15\cdots$$

Are there any $2$ triangular numbers in which the sum of those is a cube?

EDIT: Are there an infinite number of these solutions?

Comment: You can use 21 + 6 = 27

Comment: $28+36 = 4^3$, $210 + 6 = 171 + 45 = 6^3$, so it doesn't look too sparse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. There are infinitely many solutions. Let $x_1=k^3$ and $x_2=k^3-1$. Then
$$
\frac{x_1(x_1+1)}2+\frac{x_2(x_2+1)}2=k^6=(k^2)^3.
$$

Comment: Here $k=2$ gives $x_1=7$ and $x_2=8$ matching Daniel Fischer's first example.

Comment: Very nice! The less experienced among us could come up with this via the picture proof that the sum of two consecutive triangular numbers is a square number, and all square numbers are found this way. Then it reduces to finding squares that are also cubes.

Comment: That's a nice observation, @GyuEunLee!

Comment: @GyuEunLee 's method will find an infinite number of such triangular pairs, but not EVERY triangular pair.  See mathlove's answer for two others.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.$$(1+2+3)+(1+2+3+4+5+6)=6+21=3^3$$
Another example is 
$$6+210=6^3.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use [Determine if a number is the sum of two triangular numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164862/determine-if-a-number-is-the-sum-of-two-triangular-numbers). Then $n^3$ is a sum of two triangular numbers if and only if the $3 \pmod 4$ prime factors of $4n^3+1$ have even exponent.

If $n = m^2$ for some $m$, then $4n^3+1 = 4m^6+1 = (2m^3)^2+1$, so no prime factor of this is $3$ mod $4$. Hence squares $n$ work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to these infinite solutions, one can also prove that the sum of any number of consecutive cubes is equal to a triangular number squared.

That's a thing you know now.